# What are the files in /tmp that start with "qipc"?

Tags: filenames, qt, tmp, ipc

There are empty files like this in my `/tmp` directory:

```
qipc_sharedmemory_soliddiskinfomemac5ffa537fd8798875c98e190df289da7e047c05
qipc_systemsem_soliddiskinfomemac5ffa537fd8798875c98e190df289da7e047c05
qipc_systemsem_soliddiskinfosem92d02dca794587d686de797d715edb3b58944546
```

What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be files that [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) creates during the course of [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).  The file names indicate that [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) and [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) were used.

Comment: I think it's better to link directly to `QSharedMemory` and `QSemaphore` help pages instead of the generic Wikipedia pages, since these files are specific to Qt.